# Harddisk sharing for Windows and Ubuntu user

Tags: file-sharing

I have a 250gb partition of harddisk. 

I want to share this partition for another computer in my house (for **windows user** and ubuntu user).  What software did i need? Actually i find a software named "Samba". But is the software share harddisk to windows users? And can i share the harddisk through wireless connection? Is the software work on ubuntu desktop (not the server) and is it has Graphical User Interface?


Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the 250GB partition mounted when Ubuntu boots up? If not, first make sure that the partition is mounted automatically at boot. Follow this for help on editing fstab: [Mount a partition on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7310/mount-a-partition-on-login)

Let's say the partition is mounted as `/mnt/Shared`. To share this partition with another computer in the same network running Windows follow the accepted answer to this question: 
[How to transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-setup-a-lan-between-ubuntu-and-windows)

1. Open the `mnt` folder in Nautilus and right click on the `Shared`
   folder.
2. If samba is not installed, you will get a prompt to install the
   service. Follow the prompt.
3. Click on sharing option and check `Share this folder`.
4. Check "allow others to create and delete files in this folder."
5. Open a terminal by pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter

   `sudo smbpasswd -a USERNAME`

   where USERNAME is your user-id in the Ubuntu computer you are setting up.

Now you should be able to find the shared folder from other Windows and Ubuntu computers by going into `Network`.

Hope this helps