# Root, Home sizes

Tags: partitioning, root, home-directory

I'm about to install a linux distro. Wondering about which size to allocated to home and root.
I know the home partition will generally contain the user's files and stuffs. I want to know: when installing a package, does it store on the root partition, or the home? That would help me to determine which size to allocate to root and home.

Update:
Currently running Windows 8.1 Pro and Ubuntu on it.
Windows 2 partitions: 200GB, 146GB.
Ubuntu: 50GB, Swap 4GB.
New linux distro (Kali 2.0) to be installed on 50GB of unformatted space

Comment: what is hard disk size? and Is there any other OS installed on HDD?

Comment: Currently have Windows 8.1 Pro and Ubuntu 14.04 running
Windows: 200GB, 146 GB (2 partitions)
Ubuntu: 50GB, swap 4 GB
About 50GB left for the new linux distro (Kali 2.0)

Comment: as you're having only 50 GB left on HDD, you can make it 30 GB of / (root) partition and 20 GB of /home partition. /home is optional.

Comment: Generally `/home` stores your personal settings for all programs (lie bookmarks, etc.). Normally programs are installed  in `/bin/`, `/usr/bin/`, `/sbin/`.`/usr/sbin/`. Apt stores the files it download in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. So, you might need a bigger `/` than `/home`, but it all depends on your use. Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/379205/installing-programs-in-root-vs-home-partitions

Comment: "New linux distro (Kali 2.0) to be installed on 50GB of unformatted space" Kali is unsupported on AskUbuntu. But why ask this question if you have done this before? You already did what you need to do when installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually packages are installed in /usr/lib (part of root) or /opt directory.

Most of the app will use space allocated to root.

Some exceptional cases installs modules only available to single user goes in local directory.