# Installing Focal on a new PC

Tags: system-installation, ssd

Thinking of building a new PC with a small (100Gb) SSD and a larger (1TB+) spinning metal hard drive.  Will Focal's installation utility allow me to put grub and the boot files on the SSD, and /var, /etc and /home on the regular hard drive?  I've only ever take the default installation so I'm not familiar with everything it can do...

Comment: You may find this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379205/installing-programs-in-root-vs-home-partitions/379421#379421) useful.

Comment: Go ahead and install everything on the SSD. Test the system. If everything is okay, then move the `/home` directory to HD as explained in   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.  My logic regarding /etc and /var is that lots of customizations take place in those two filesystems whereas / and grub are relatively static beyond periodic updates.

Comment: Not sure how it helps to put boot on a SSD if you put everything it loads on a HDD. I put root on a SSD and home on a HDD and that works okay.

Comment: Mostly because I want the files on the SSD to be pretty static, whereas the files on the HDD are more likely to be updated more often, that's all.