# OS on SSD says it's full but not

Tags: boot, files, filesystem, ssd

Been using Ubuntu for years but with old computers with big hard drives. New computer has a standard hard drive and a solid state as well. After install(Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) it put OS on the SSD which is nice cause it loads super fast. But recently it keeps saying system is full. But Disks shows two partitions but overall it says it's 1.2 percent full. I'm sorry but I don't know much about partitions and how that all works but I'd like to have all my files on Home put on the hard drive and then I'd like the SSD to just be used for the operating system and other programs. Can anyone take a minute and teach us about partitions and how I can get this right. Appreciate any help!

GParted looks like this:

[image]

Sorry if I'm doing this wrong, first time asking a question, but someone asked for this:

```
$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1897400k,nr_inodes=474350,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=386544k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18738)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap on /snap/bare/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_13425.snap on /snap/core/13425 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2560.snap on /snap/core18/2560 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_13741.snap on /snap/core/13741 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2566.snap on /snap/core18/2566 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1623.snap on /snap/core20/1623 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1611.snap on /snap/core20/1611 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_1670.snap on /snap/firefox/1670 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gimp_393.snap on /snap/gimp/393 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gimp_383.snap on /snap/gimp/383 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_1810.snap on /snap/firefox/1810 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_112.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_161.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk2-common-themes_13.snap on /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_115.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1534.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004_2.snap on /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_582.snap on /snap/snap-store/582 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pinta_19.snap on /snap/pinta/19 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_16778.snap on /snap/snapd/16778 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_10.snap on /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_14.snap on /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_16292.snap on /snap/snapd/16292 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_592.snap on /snap/snap-store/592 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=386540k,nr_inodes=96635,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=386544k,mode=755,inode64)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt type nsfs (rw)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snapd-desktop-integration.mnt type nsfs (rw)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/firefox.mnt type nsfs (rw)
```

And:

```
$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             386544     2224    384320   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  13220136 12046392    480396  97% /
tmpfs            1932704        0   1932704   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1    523248     5364    517884   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             386540     4740    381800   2% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1430606/edit) and add the following information: 1. The version of Ubuntu you are using. 2. A screenshot of the app **Gparted** showing the SSD in your computer. You may have to install Gparted first. Use the "picture icon" above the edit window to add a link to the screenshot in your question. This will help us understand the partitions you have in your SSD and which one of them is full.

Comment: Please show the exact message in your question, preferably copy&paste it. Open a terminal window, run the commands `mount` and `df -k` and copy&paste the commands with their output to your question. Format this text as a code block by putting  `~~~` before and after it as separate lines or by using the `{}` tool of the editor field.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379205/installing-programs-in-root-vs-home-partitions/379421#379421) for a possible solution. Follow the step 5 of the [accepted answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu) to move some of the contents of your Home to the HDD.